# I'm getting error with Keystore file in GitHub Actions with flutter build apk

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions

I'm getting the error
´´´Keystore file '/Users/runner/work/Quiz-App/Quiz-App/android/app/keystore/upload-keystore.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.´´´
when trying to build my android app written in Flutter using GitHub Actions.

This is my workflow yml file:

`https://pastebin.com/96tvjAEj´

And this is the snippet inside build.gradle in android/app that I use:

´https://pastebin.com/ws3Djk7M´

It's expecting this file in /Users/runner/work/Project-Name/Project-Name/android/app/keystore/upload-keystore.jks

but I think it can't find it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site to a pastebin to read your code. Please [edit] your question and include a [mre] _here_.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are NOT uploading your keystore file with your github commits. Which does make sense because it's a security issue to have them checked into version control.
Read the error again, it is telling you the exact problem. You can overcome it by uploading your keystore to the path specified, or go to .gitignore and remove it from there so it get's uploaded with your code pushes.

Comment: I'm trying using GitHub repository secrets to provide that without uploading this file. I don't want to upload it. I think I need the correct path to use.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error and fixed it by creating a **keystore/** folder within **/android/app/** then put the **upload-keystore.jks** file inside. My folder wasn't named **keystore** though.